# Is becoming registered eFiler associated with any fees?

Tags: fees

If I'm not mistaken, becoming registered eFiler (Pro Se) involves 3 steps.

1. Creating USPTO account at https://my.uspto.gov
2. Filling and sending Request for Customer Number - form PTO/SB/125A
3. Filling and sending Patent Electronic System Verification Form - PTO‐2042a

Is any of these steps associated with any fees, or is this completely free?

If one eventually becomes registered eFiler, but then finds out that
his invention is not patentable, so he actually never fills any application,
does that have any consequences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is any of these steps associated with any fees**

No, none whatsoever as of now.

**... actually never fills any application, does that have any consequences**

Again the answer is 'NO'.

If one does not use one's account and does not change password regularly then USPTO account gets locked. Access to private PAIR also gets locked after a certain time period. Both are of course retrievable.